Is there a way to remove the background from an image without using an api?
Is there a way to remove the background from an image without using an api?
I tried using remove_background but it didnt work
final Uint8List imageBytes = await File(pickedImage.path).readAsBytes();
      image = await removeBackground(imageBytes: imageBytes);
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });


I'm not sure what you mean/expect from "without using an api". Did you check https://www.google.com/search?q=flutter+remove+background+from+image, which seems to have many ways to remove the background from an image in Flutter?

https://pub.dev/packages/local_rembg perhaps?
